# How to Initialize View that has initWithCoder: method

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, nscoder, autorotate

I have a view that is initialized with - `(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder`
How do I initialize this view in a `viewController`?

I think I need the `viewController` if I want the view to `autoRotate` with the device. I am not sure, maybe I could accomplish the `autoRotation` without a `viewController`?

Adding a observer and `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` to the view did not autoRotate the view. But when I also add

```
-(void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *) notification 
{
    NSLog(@"orientationChanged: %d", [[notification object] orientation]);
}
```

I get the orientation value in my console window.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initWithCoder:` is for managing serialized objects. You never call it directly. An object with an `initWithCoder:` method should still have a regular designated initializer (for a view, it would be `initWithFrame:`). Generally, however, I recommend using a nib file rather than trying to build this stuff by hand. It greatly simplifies things, and loading from a nib file will call `initWithCoder:`.

Managing autorotation with a view controller is much simpler. It's not required, but it does do some of the work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I used the initWithFrame: method and everything works great. I just needed a little push.